# Dart - Converting Milliseconds Since Epoch (UNIX timestamp) into human readable time

Tags: dart, unix-timestamp, datetime-conversion

Is there a good way to parse milliseconds since epoch (ex. 1486252500000 13 digits) formatted time into a human readable format?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`DateTime` does have a named constructor for millisecond since epoch

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html

`DateTime date = new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1486252500000)`

If you want to convert it to human readable string, you can use [intl](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl) package with the [DateFormat](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/0.15.1/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class

```
import "package:intl/intl_browser.dart";

var format = new DateFormat("yMd");
var dateString = format.format(date);
```

Comment: Please include the library import path also.  I tried "import "package:intl/intl_browser.dart";"

Comment: @AjithMemana search by the library name at Pub.Dev, also an embedded link has been provided.